# Recommended font size for certain screen width

Tags: css, accessibility, font-size

I'm designing a webpage using `font-size: calc(26px - ((26 - 16) * (1600px - 100vw) / (1600 - 300)));` for font-size interpolation, but the problem is, I'm not comfortable with the maximums `(26px, 1600px)` and minimums `(16px, 300px)` of the chosen font-sizes and view port widths respectively. What are the recommended font-sizes for different screen widths?

Comment: Dear Bright, you are referring to 'not comfortable' uses these sizes, could you mentions the reasons why your not comfortable? Is this too big? Or small? (also, sometimes the font-family make a huge difference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Font sizes should never go under 16px.** It will make life harder for older ones and people with eye problems.

---

You don't need to use those complicated calculations. Instead, you can use `min()`, `max()` or `clamp()`

**Beware**: These functions are relatively new (especially `clamp()`). Check [this link out](http://caniuse.com/#search=clamp()) to see browser support.

`min()` Lets you to choose minimum and recommended font-size:

```
min(18px, 2vw) /* It will use minimum of those two */
```

`max()` chooses between two values and uses bigger one:

```
max(18px, 2vw) /* If 2wv becomes smaller than 18px, it will not use it */
```

`clamp()` Is combination of those two. You can choose minimum, regular and maximum font value:

```
clamp(18px, 2vw, 50px) /* If 2wv becomes smaller than 18px, it will not use it. If 2vw gets bigger than 50px, it will stay at 50px */
```

---

Learn more:

[`min(), max()` and `clamp` (Excellent youtube video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9VF-4euyRo)

Comment: I love those new CSS 'functions' :-) I want to mention that clamp() is pretty new. I just to like to drop the 'caniuse' link for OP. https://caniuse.com/#search=clamp()

Comment: @ArnoTenkink added it to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I've learnt something new.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there isn't really a 'rule' about maximum font-size. This depends on the nature of the context and word-count. You can also play around by making the first paragraph bigger or even bolder to introduce to the text and make it a small summary.

The main concern is the minimum values. iOS tends to zoom in any paragraph of web-content that below the 16px mark. This count for the main body content. The Google Material Design UI also recommends to use 16px as minimum body text-size. **16px mimics the normal size of a book page.**

Minimum for desktop can be between 16-18px, what seems to fit the style the most.

Some recources:

https://material.io/design/typography/the-type-system.html#type-scale

https://w3-lab.com/web-design/how-big-should-a-font-be-on-a-site-rules-of-typography/

Comment: Well explained. Great answer!